# Работа с нескольким таблицами SQL на WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms, sql

Добрый день.
Имеется несколько таблиц БД MSSQL реализация Winforms C#, вопрос в следующем необходимо реализовать работу по добавлению/редактированию записей как в подобных случаях принято поступать: 
для каждой таблицы создавать отдельные формы или создавать форму и динамически заполнять её в зависимости от состава полей используемой таблицы?

Answer (score 1):

Данный вопрос зависит не от того, что делает приложение, а от того, как оно это делает. Если элементы интерфейса и логика остаются одинаковыми от табицы к таблице, к примеру использование отображения на DataGrid, то плодить формы нет смысла. Если же для каждой таблицы у вас свой интерфейс, к примеру "рабочие" и "товары" и для каждой отдельная формочка красивая, то возможно стоит подумать о разбиение на различные формы.